# How to send a file using CURL command via rest API with cookie?

Tags: rest, api, curl, file-upload, multipartform-data

I am unable to send a cookie with Curl command while consuming rest API.
By using rest API we are trying to upload/send a file to server.

VVIMP: same is working fine with Postman

We have tried below CURL command:

```
curl -X POST https://serversite.com:443\apipath -H "accept: application/xml" -H "accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br" -H "accept-language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8" -H "cache-control: no-cache" -H "connection: keep-alive" -H "content-type: multipart/form-data" -H "origin: https://serversite.com:443" -H "user-agent:  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36" -c "Cookie: _app_vis_id_=790FC6B0F5AE014A5E52A8B162CC129B" -F "file=C:\temp\upload.txt" -F "param1=value1" -F "param2=value2"  >> "C:\temp\myfile.txt"
```

We are getting below server response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<result>
    <header>
        <code>Rj209</code>
        <message>Session not found</message>
    </header>
</result>


Expected response is:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<result>
    <header>
        <code>Rj200</code>
        <message>Success</message>
    </header>
    <body>
        <data>
            <items>
                <item>
                    <objectType>SHARE_FILE</objectType>
                    <keyValue>
                        <key>id</key>
                        <value>52</value>
                    </keyValue>
                    <keyValue>
                        <key>version</key>
                        <value>4</value>
                    </keyValue>
                </item>
            </items>
        </data>
    </body>
</result>
```